# Thymeleaf: add HTML to th:replace function

Tags: html, thymeleaf

I would like to add some HTML in the **th:replace** function in Thymeleaf, like so:

```
<div th:replace="elements/listview :: row (subtext='Test<br />Test')" ></div>
```

My 'listview' template is like this:

```
 <div class="listview-row" th:fragment="row">
            <span class="listview-subtext" th:if="${subtext != null}" th:utext="${subtext}">

            </span>
        </div>
```

It doesn't compile. Of course I want it to compile as:

```
 <div class="listview-row">
            <span class="listview-subtext">
                Test<br />Test
            </span>
        </div>
```

.. with the HTML in place. Is there any way to do that? Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: i think it should work. but when you do `th:replace="elements/listview :: row (text='Test<br />Test')"`, you specify the param name to be `text` but then in the fragment you are checking for `subtext`. either use `text` as the param name inside the fragment, or just parameterise the fragment

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I edited that part, it was a typo. :)

Comment: did it work or ... ?

Comment: No that is not the problem. Is just doesn't compile - it sees HTML as faulty code.

Comment: and you are sure this is what is causing the problem? can you try commenting this block out and check everything else works?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```html
<div class="listview-row" th:fragment="row(subtext)">
            <span class="listview-subtext" th:if="${subtext != null}" th:utext="${subtext}">

            </span>
        </div>
```

and use it like this:

```html
<div th:replace="elements/listview :: row ('Test<br />Test')" ></div>
```